Elliptic Equations with sign-changing zeroth order coefficient
I came across an elliptic equation
$$ Lu = 0, \quad u \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$$
where
$$ L := \sum a_{ij}(x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} +\sum b_i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} +c(x) $$
and the coefficients $a_{ij}$ satisfy the elliptic condition.
Assume that $c(x)$ changes sign and is bounded( periodic in $x$ for example). I want to get some maximum principle type results like
$$Lu \geq 0 \text{   implies   } \sup_{\overline{\Omega}} u \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega} u$$
Are there any known results about this kind of problems?
